# Firebase: cut dynamic links programmatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to share the content of the app as dynamic link (constructed in app), but link is looked cumbersome. How can I make the link shorter?

Comment: You can use goo.gl `API` for `Java` : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/urlshortener/v1

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Firebase do not support create dynamic link via API.

You can however create self constructed url then using 3-party service such as Google URL shortener to shorten the url

Answer (score 1):

As of early October 2016, you can now shorten Dynamic Links programmatically via a REST API call:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/short-links

Copying the examples from the link above, you can do it one of two ways:

### Shortening an existing long link:

```
POST https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=api_key
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "longDynamicLink": "https://abc123.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com/&apn=com.example.android&ibi=com.example.ios"
}
```

### Building from link parameters

```
POST https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=api_key
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "dynamicLinkDomain": "abc123.app.goo.gl",
    "link": "https://example.com/",
    "androidInfo": {
      {
        "androidPackageName": "com.example.android"
      }
    },
    "iosInfo": {
      {
        "iosBundleId": "com.example.ios"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that using a general-purpose URL shortening solution such as Bitly, does not give you the analytics that a short Dynamic Link gives you.